# MATLAB: how to "equally distribute" the Trues in each column of a full lower triangular logical matrix over the columns of m new matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, bisection

My first question on stackoverflow! The title is vague, so let me elaborate: I have a NxN lower triangular logical matrix

```
N = 10    % for example
L = tril(true(N),-1)
L =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

with all trues below the diagonal. For a m=2^p a power of 2, I want to end up with m NxN lower triangular logical matrices L_1, ..., L_m such that each column of L_i contains the i-th 1/m-th (rounded) number of the Trues in the corresponding column in L. One consequence is that \sum_i(L_i) == L again.

For example, for m = 2 I know that

```
L_2 = L(:,ceil((N:2*N-1)/2))
L_2 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
L_1 = L - L_2
L_1 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

will do the trick, but this trick does not generalize to higher powers of 2 for m. Any ideas how to do this reasonably fast for general N and m = 2^p?

(Context: each column of L are logical indices for a bisection type algorithm. Every next power p of m = 2^p corresponds to a deeper level of the bisection algorithm)